# VPN Email Alert by IP address (Bash Script)

Tags: bash, script, bash-scripting

I have an OpenVPN server, when a user connects to the server they are given an IP from 192.168.1.20-25. I want to get an alert when these IP's reply back as well as when they disconnect.

So far I can get this to work with the following code as you can see it does not take into consideration when it should send an email as it will simply loop and mass email without any disregard.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS_ARRAY=("192.168.1.20" "192.168.20.21" "192.168.20.22" "192.168.20.23" "192.168.20.24" "192.168.20.25")
COUNT=4
for myHost in "${HOSTS_ARRAY[@]}"
do
     count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | a$
     if [ $count -eq 1 ]; then
         echo " VPN User Connected!" | mail -s "VPN User Connected" myadress@gmail.com
         echo "Host : $myHost Connected! at $(date)"
else
         echo " VPN User Disconnected!" | mail -s "VPN User Disconnected" myadress@gmail.com
         echo "Host : $myHost Disconnected! at $(date)"
     fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a persistently running script try using the learn-address directive in your server.conf. This will allow you to run a script whenever a new user connects and disconnects.

The script is called with the following arguments:
$1: add, update, delete
$2: client IP address
$3: common name on the certificate

The only gotchas are that it appears that the script is only run with delete when the user is cleaned up after disconnecting, and the server needs to be run with script-security 2. You also need to make sure the script is executable by whatever user the server is being run as (check the user and group directives in the server.conf)